# INSERT INTO a large amount of data with many clients running SELECT

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, locking, insert, blocking

I need to run a query like this to insert a large amount of data (millions of rows) into a MySQL table (InnoDB, 5.6.10):

```
INSERT INTO target_table (a)
SELECT id FROM source_table
ON DUPLICATE KEY a=a;
```

This usually takes around 200 seconds to run when no clients are accessing `target_table`.

`target_table` now has around 20 clients 'polling' to see if data has arrived, so we now have a lot of clients performing queries like this one:

```
SELECT a FROM target_table WHERE a LIKE '0%';
```

I'm having trouble with the `INSERT INTO` statement now that these clients are polling - it fails with the error `Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`.

I'm a bit confused as to why whatever lock is required for `INSERT INTO` cannot be acquired because clients are running `SELECT` statements.

#### EDIT:

The `CREATE` statements for these tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `target_table` (
  `a` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`),
  CONSTRAINT `target_table_source_table` FOREIGN KEY (`a`) REFERENCES `source_table` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `source_table` (
  `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name_index` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Is there a _leading_ wildcard on the `LIKE` string?

Comment: @rick-james No, no leading wildcard, but a trailing wildcard.

Comment: _If_ you have a key starting with `a`, then that should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `source_table`, are there often duplicate values?  I assume `a` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `dest_table`?  If there are often dups, change to

```
INSERT INTO target_table
    SELECT DISTINCT a FROM source_table
ON DUPLICATE KEY a=a;
```

`DISTINCT` moves work into the `SELECT`, thereby lessening the conflicts over the `INSERT`.

Better yet, do this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO target_table
    SELECT DISTINCT a FROM source_table;
```

`IGNORE` is probably less work than IODKU.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables; there could be subtle issues, especially with the `PRIMARY KEY`, timestamps, and secondary indexes.

Comment: I originally chose the `ON DUPLICATE` approach to avoid other errors being ignored. Could you explain how switching to `IGNORE` would help? I've added the `CREATE` statements to the original post. Really appreciate your input, thanks!

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: No duplicate value in source_table (we're selecting only the PK), the `ON DUPLICATE` was there just in case target_table already contained the value.

Comment: Switching from `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to `INSERT IGNORE` seems to have solved the problem, thanks!